# Register class methods with nusoap

Tags: php, nusoap

I've a php class and i want to use it with [Nusoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/). Can I register the class method's that already exists inside the nusoap with the register command?

Sample :

Here we register a function that we defined inside this script. But if we've a class that we maybe develop months ago and we want to use it as a webservice using the WSDL. Is there a way to register the methods of that class so that Nusoap creates a WSDL of it's stucture (methods inside)?

```
require_once("nuSOAP/lib/nusoap.php");

$server = new soap_server();

$namespace = "http://localhost/nusoapSCRIPT/index.php";

$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;

$server->configureWSDL("SAMPLE");

$server->register('HelloWorld');

function HelloWorld()
{
return "Hello, World!";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give an example of some sort?

Comment: i've edited my question with an example... hope this clarify my question a bit. Thanks

Comment: You wrote you would like to register methods of some class. In your example you register a global function. Do you want to register a class function instead? Just asking have problems to specifically understand your question.

Comment: Yes that's my question about... this example register local functions as you said. But right, i asked how to register class method's.

Comment: I'm not very fluent with NuSOAP so I can't tell your directly. It might be possible but it might be not (or you need to write a wrapper). NuSOAP docs are here for download: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/files/nusoap-docs/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well here's how i solve this... maybe someone can try an approach in another way.

```
[File : index.php]
require_once "nuSOAP/lib/nusoap.php";    
require_once "myClass.class.inc.php";

$namespace = "http://localhost/html/nusoap/index.php";

// create a new soap server
$server = new soap_server();

// configure our WSDL
$server->configureWSDL("Class Example");

// set our namespace
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;

// register the class method and the params of the method
$server->register("myClass.ShowString"                       
                 ,array('name'=>'xsd:string')
                 ,array('return'=>'xsd:string')
                 ,$namespace,false
                 ,'rpc'
                 ,'encoded'
                 ,'Sample of embedded classes...' 
                                );

//
// Get our posted data if the service is being consumed
// otherwise leave this data blank.                
$POST_DATA = isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']) 
                ? $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] : '';

// pass our posted data (or nothing) to the soap service                    
$server->service($POST_DATA);                
exit();
```

and the class code.

```
[File 'myClass.class.inc.php']

class myClass{

     public function __construct(){

     }


     public function ShowString($mens){

        return "\n##Remote Class :".__CLASS__."\n##Remote Method : ".__METHOD__."\n## mSG :{$mens}";

     }

}
```

I also create a soap client in c# and it consumes correctly the soap service.

Hope this help!

Comment: Ok, fine. But how it's look the call :) $client = new SoapClient(); and $client->myClass.ShowString? :) Because I couldn't make it to work :(

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the nusoap proxy which prevents it to work with class encapsulated functions. If you use `$client->call('ImplClass.myfunc');` it works nicely. What this leaves unresolved is that you cannot extend your SOAP interface iteratively by inheriting from the implementing class.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method using `getProxy()`

```
$proxy->className__methodname
```