# Registering namespaced PHP class methods with NuSoap

Tags: php, soap, autoload, nusoap

Is it possible to register a PHP autoloaded namespaced class method with the NuSoap library?  To be clear, the PHP class is namespaced.  This is not a question about XML namespacing.

For example, if I had a class defined in some file:

```
<?php

  namespace \My\Fancy\Namespace;

  class MyClass {
       public static function foo() { /* ... */ }
       // ...
  }
```

and I wanted to register it with my soap server:

```
    <?php

    use \My\Fancy\Namespace\MyClass; // autoloaded

    $server = new soap_server();

    // ... server configuration ...

    $server->register(
        'MyClass..foo'  // This does not work
        // ... etc. ...
    );
```

I've run so many searches for this with no luck, so I hope I'm not asking a bad question.

Comment: @Alex, I don't believe this is a duplicate as that question deals with soap/XML namespaces, not PHP namespaces.

Comment: I am also searching solution for the same problem!! damn! when i got ur question on the google search i was happy and hoped it will solve mine :-/

Comment: @jpheldson Found any solution?

Comment: @RafiqueMohammed, sadly I never did for this particular issue.  Best of luck.

Comment: Maybe similar question is asked here in stack-overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083059/register-class-methods-with-nusoap

Comment: @kapilyadav There is some similarity in that we both wanted to register a class method, but my issue is specifically related to a class that is not in PHP's root namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On **nusoap_server** class in **invoke_method** method, the code does not allow to use namespaces.

```
function invoke_method() {
    // many lines of code...

    $class = '';
    $method = '';
    if (strlen($delim) > 0 && substr_count($this->methodname, $delim) == 1) {
        $try_class = substr($this->methodname, 0, strpos($this->methodname, $delim));
        if (class_exists($try_class)) {
            // get the class and method name
            $class = $try_class;
            $method = substr($this->methodname, strpos($this->methodname, $delim) + strlen($delim));
            $this->debug("in invoke_method, class=$class method=$method delim=$delim");
        } else {
            $this->debug("in invoke_method, class=$try_class not found");
        }
    } else {
        $try_class = '';
        $this->debug("in invoke_method, no class to try");
    }

    // many lines of code...
}
```

But thank god for open source so lets modify the code!
This is what you could do:

```
function invoke_method() {
    // many lines of code...

    $class = '';
    $method = '';
    if (strlen($delim) > 0 && substr_count($this->methodname, $delim) == 1) {
        $try_class = substr($this->methodname, 0, strpos($this->methodname, $delim));
        if (class_exists($try_class)) {
            // get the class and method name
            $class = $try_class;
            $method = substr($this->methodname, strpos($this->methodname, $delim) + strlen($delim));
            $this->debug("in invoke_method, class=$class method=$method delim=$delim");
        } else {
            $this->debug("in invoke_method, class=$try_class not found");
        }
    } elseif (strlen($delim) > 0 && substr_count($this->methodname, $delim) > 1) {
        $split = explode($delim, $this->methodname);
        $method = array_pop($split);
        $class = implode('\\', $split);
    } else {
        $try_class = '';
        $this->debug("in invoke_method, no class to try");
    }

    // many lines of code...
}
```

Explaining:

```
// Example of namespaced class
// $this->methodname = 'Namespace.Namespace2.Class.MethodName';

// Has delimiter "." or ".." more than one time.
if (strlen($delim) > 0 && substr_count($this->methodname, $delim) > 1) {
    // code below
}

// Transform in array
$split = explode($delim, $this->methodname);
// $split = array('Namespace', 'Namespace2', 'Class', 'MethodName')

// Get the last item (method name) and remove from array.
$method = array_pop($split);
// $method = 'MethodName'
// $split = array('Namespace', 'Namespace2', 'Class')

// Transform the class name
$class = implode('\\', $split);
// $class = 'Namespace\Namespace2\Class'
```

With this simple modification you can have the PHP namespace feature working.
I know that a long time passes but I hope to help some one with this answer.